# Is there a function to paste NA_character_?

Tags: r

As expected, the base R `paste()` function coerces `NA_character_` to `"NA"`.

From the documentation of the base R paste() function:

> Note that `paste()` coerces `NA_character_`, the character missing value, to `"NA"` which may seem undesirable, e.g., when pasting two character vectors, or very desirable, e.g. in `paste("the value of p is ", p)`.

example:

```
paste(NA_character_)
```

returns `"NA"`

Is there a function (`magicFunction` in the example below) that preserves `NA_character_`?
i.e. that

```
magicFunction(NA_character_)
```

would return `NA` and not `"NA"`?

I woudld like to use the function in the following context:

```
library(tidyverse)
toColumn = list(df1 = tibble(letts = c("a","b",NA_character_,"c")),
                df2 = tibble(letts = c("alpha","beta",NA_character_,"gamma")),
                df3 = tibble(letts = c(NA_character_)))
                
final_df  = toColumn %>% purrr::map(~.x %>% dplyr::pull(letts) %>%
  paste(.,collapse=";") %>% dplyr::tibble(pasted_letts = .) ) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.)
```

where the third row of the final data frame column "pasted_letts" contains `"NA"` and I would like to preserve the `NA_character_`  of the original data frame `df3` in order to use e.g. is.na() for filtering, mutate etc..

Comment: Why are you showing the result of `is.na(paste(c(NA_character_)))`? How is this relevant for your question, and why would you expect this expression to be `TRUE`? Oh, and you don’t need to use `c(…)` around single values, it’s redundant here.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help! I will add an exmaple of what I actually want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your own:

```
paste_keep_na = function (..., sep = ' ', collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE) {
    if (...length() == 1L && length(..1) == 1L && is.na(..1)) {
        return(..1)
    }
    paste(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, recycle0 = recycle0)
}
```

Note that this will only test the *first* argument. If you pass multiple values (or a single value with multiple elements), the function will behave like regular `paste`, which is *probably* what’s expected.